# How to show a calendar when a button is clicked and display the selected date in a label?- iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a selectDateLabel and a selecteDateButton. How to show a calendar when I click the selecteDateButton and display the selected date on the selectDateLabel?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a built in calendar date picker, but a regular [UIDatePicker](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidatepicker) might work for you.

edit: Or go with an open source library like [PDTSimpleCalendar](https://github.com/jivesoftware/PDTSimpleCalendar)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"cccc, MMM d, hh:mm aa"];
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

write this code in your button Action.

Comment: it unable to show the date picker when the button is clicked.

Comment: see the edited answer. it will show you date in console.
If you want a graphical  calendar then see the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you complete graphical date picker.

Button click method

```
- (IBAction)btnDel:(id)sender {
        UIDatePicker* datPick = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
        datPick.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        datPick.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
        [datPick addTarget:self action:@selector(dueDateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        CGSize pickerSize = [datPick sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
        datPick.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 300, pickerSize.width, 300);
        [self.view addSubview:datPick];   
    }

    -(void) dueDateChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender {
        NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
        [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
        NSLog(@"Picked the date %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[sender date]]);
    }
```